# Says "package ... does not exist" despite its JAR is inserted

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, jar, react-android

I've built [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/building-from-source.html) and copied the created `*.jar` packages into `libs` folder that is placed in the root directory of `ReactAndroid` project like the following:

directory setup:

```
- node_modules
  - ReactAndroid
    - libs
      - drawee-1.3.0-sources.jar
      - fbcore-1.3.0-sources.jar
    - src
      - main
        - java
        - libraries
    - build.gradle
```

`build.gradle` file:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile (name:'drawee-1.3.0-sources', ext:'jar')
    compile (name:'fbcore-1.3.0-sources', ext:'jar')
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs', './libs'
        }
    }
}
...
```

When trying to run the command of `./gradlew installDebug` it throws errors for the all classes that are added in `*.jar` packages like the below:

```
/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/UIViewOperationQueue.java:13: error: package com.facebook.common.logging does not exist

import com.facebook.common.logging.FLog;
```

However `FLog` class is present in `fbcore-1.3.0-sources.jar` package.
(at com/facebook/common/logging/FLog.java path)

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

---

### Edit:

Using `*.aar` packages instead of `*.jar` has solved the issue.

Comment: You can't use `sources` jars (with `.java` files) as dependencies. Either add the jar with the compiled library (with `.class` files) or add the source files to a source set to compile them.

Comment: @lu.koerfer thank you very much. Could you please show me an example? It could be an answer if you prefer.

Comment: Is this what you meant? -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Is there any specific reason for you to build Fresco from source instead of using the [provided compiled version](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html)? Did you modify Fresco source code?

Comment: Yes exactly I have a big reason (https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1870) unfortunately...

Comment: If I can use *.jar files in a project I can show some console logs I put. Maybe  I'll figure the issue out. Hopefully...

Comment: Well, the main problem is that you are simply using the wrong `.jar` files. If you execute `gradlew build`, it should create compiled versions of the libraries, you can either copy them manually to your project, include the projects into your own Gradle project or use a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Comment: Amm.. After building these folders have been created `generated`, `intermediates`, `libs` (contains jar files `fbcore-debug.aar` and `fbcore-release.aar`), `outputs` (contain __`aar`__ file), `reports`, `test-results` and `tmp`. So, should I use `aar` file instead `jar` in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165875/discussion-between-lu-koerfer-and-efkan).